# Which is the right order of the conditional tags on pages?

Tags: conditional-tags

I need to develope a structure where I use all the conditionals for every type of page, post and archive.

On WordPress we have these pages (extracted from a template hierarchy):

- Error 404 Page
- Search Result Page
- Archive Page
- - Custom Taxonomy
- - Category Archive
- - Tag Archive
- - Author Archive
- - Date Archive
- - - Year Archive
- - - Month Archive
- - - Day Archive
- - Custom Post-Type Archive
- Singular Page
- - Single Post Page
- - - Attachment Post
- - - Custom Post
- - - Blog Post
- - Static Page
- - - Page Template
- Site Front Page
- Blog Posts Index Page
- Comments Popup Page

According to these tree, if I have a WordPress theme with all these pages, I need a structure to avoid bugs, knowing that it's possible to change Blog Posts Index Page for a Site Front Page, and using an another Static Page as it was the Blog Index/Archive.

```
is_home()
```

↑ This is only TRUE when the Blog Index is shown in the Front Page.

```
is_front_page()
```

↑ This conditional returns TRUE when it is the Blog Index or a Static Page
.

```
is_front_page() and is_home()
```

↑ There is no conditional tag for the blog page. So this code helps to detect this page. The right order to avoid bugs is this:

```
if ( is_front_page() && is_home() ) {
    // Default homepage
} elseif ( is_front_page() ) {
    // static homepage
} elseif ( is_home() ) {
    // blog page
} else {
    // everything else
}
```

Then, let's see how it would be:

```
if ( is_front_page() && is_home() ) {
    //...
} elseif ( is_front_page() ) {
    //...
} elseif ( is_home() ) {
    //--------------------------------
} elseif ( is_post_type_arachive() ) {
    //...
} elseif ( is_tax() ) {
    //...
} elseif ( is_author() ) {
    //...
} elseif ( is_tag() ) {
    //...
} elseif ( is_category() ) {
    //...
} elseif ( is_year() ) {
    //...
} elseif ( is_month() ) {
    //...
} elseif ( is_day() ) {
    //...
} elseif ( is_date() ) {
    //...
} elseif ( is_archive() ) {
    //... Else: any archive page
    //--------------------------------
} elseif ( is_attachment() ) {
    //...
} elseif ( is_single() ) {
    //--------------------------------
} elseif ( is_page_template() ) {
    //...
} elseif ( is_page() ) {
    //--------------------------------
} elseif ( is_singular() ) {
    //... Else: any singular page
    //--------------------------------
} elseif ( is_404() ) {
    //...
} elseif ( is_search() ) {
    //...
} elseif ( is_paged() ) {
    //... Additional settings
    //... for paged archives.
}
```

I want to use it for several features: breadcrumbs, meta information (Open Graph, meta tags), or simply to customize the titles.

Is it the right order?

Should I use `is_main_query()` at some point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no real correct order in which to use the conditionals. A general rule of thumb is to put the most used condition first and the least used last

I also think that a switch will be a bit better here as it will be bit faster. Normal else/if statements re-evalutes the statement before executing, where as switches doesn't re-evalutes the conditions.

Just a note, `is_archive()` will return true on all archives, so be careful with that. On the point on frontpages and blogpages, you can go and check [this recent post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/174342/31545) I have done

The conditional `is_main_query()` is not needed. It is basically just needed where something can influence the main query and custom queries like `pre_get_posts`

### EDIT

A basic switch normally evaluates to true. If a condition evaluates to true, execution of the switch stops and the value is output from the switch. Here is a basic switch

```
switch ( true ) {

case (is_home() ):

    $text = 'This is home';

    break;

case ( is_category() ):

    $text = 'This is a category page';

    break;

case ( is_tag() ):

    $text = 'This is a tag page';

    break;

default:

    $text = 'This is not home, category or tag pages';

    break;

}
```

You can now output $text in your header like

```
echo $text;
```

This is just something simple and should give you a basic idea

Comment: Let me ask one thing related to it: in order to initialize the variable of the switch statement, what value should I use in that case? I can't find any example nor idea.

Comment: I'm using `$selectpage = get_post_type( get_the_ID() );` and it's working at the moment. Then, `case ( is_front_page() ):` and so on.

Comment: Good morning, please see my edit. Hope is helps :-)

Comment: It was so easy and I was complicating it. It works perfect, now! Thank you!

Comment: My pleasure. Enjoy :-)